# how to extract intent filters of android application installed on device programmatically

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Is there any way to extract the intent filters used by the application installed on android device through java code? i have tried a lot by using flag `GET_INTENT_FILTERS` but failed to get intent filters.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you asking for getting the list of installed apps in the Android device?

Comment: No. I have obtained the list of installed apps on android device. I extracted the permissions, services and broadcast receivers of android apps programmatically. now i want to obtain the intent filters of android apps that are installed on the android device. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: still waiting for the solution. Hope this question get attention.